# Trouble solving equation, finding dimensions of rectangles with shared side (given perimeter)

Tags: rectangles

You will build a rectangular sheep pen next to a river. There is no need to build a fence along the river, so you only need to build three sides. You have a total of 450 feet of fence to use. Find the dimensions of the pen such that you can enclose the maximum area.

Comment: What have you tried?  Make two variables, one for the length and one for the width.  The area is the product.  The $450$ gives a relation between them, so plug that in and have an equation for the area as a function of one.  Differentiate, set to zero,.....  Where is your problem?

Comment: He probably cannot use calculus, this is a fairly low-level question.

Comment: -b/2a works instead though, so I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this is to set $x$ to be the width of the rectangle and $y$ to be the length.

Therefore: $2x+y=450$, because of the restriction on the perimeter. $xy=$ the area.

Let us solve for $y$ in terms of $x$.

$y=450-2x$

Therefore, our area is $x(450-2x)$ or $-2x^2+450x$. Since this is an upside-down parabola (the negative coefficient on the $x^2$-value), we can use $-\frac{b}{2a}$ to find the maximum.

Our $b$ = 450, and $a=-2$, so we have the maximum area at the $x$-value:

$$x=-\frac{450}{-4}$$
$$x=112.5$$
By our first definition: $y=450-2x$

$$y=450-2 \cdot 112.5$$
$$y=225$$

Our maximum dimensions are length $225$ and width $112.5$, with area being $25312.5$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We differentiate function of area wrt a and equating it with 0 SO that we can calc. a for which area will be max.

Comment: He may not have calculus, this is a low level question that is normally asked in Algebra I or Geometry...

Comment: I think u are right